# Comparando cadenas String en Java

Tags: java

Pregunta de un ignorante, en java, porque no funciona esto?

```
nombre = S.nextLine();
nombre= nombre.toLowerCase();
if(nombre.equals("juan") || nombre.equals("pedro"))
{
...
}
```

Me lo toma como siempre distinto, como que el String no pueda ser comparado pasandome el else como la opcion correcta.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: y no puede ser que nombre no sea ninguno de esos dos?

Comment: lo que intento decir es que ingresando juan o pedro tampoco toma la comparacion, como si fuere siempre distinto de "juan", hay algun tipo de particularidad a observar en los datos de tipo string?

Comment: no, pero estas seguro que tu variable nombre contiene alguno de esos nombres?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta solo usando:
nombre = S.next();

Al usar nextLine(), te considera la linea en la que presionas el enter.

Nos cuentas, Saludos_!

Comment: Hola bienvenido. mira [answer] para ver como hacer una linda respuesta. Por lo pronto, solemos esperar a que quien pregunta aclare bien la duda, asi no armamos respuestas que requieran clarificacion del usuario. Gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: de paso, mira [tour] para saber como funcionamos!

Comment: te amo jonathan, era eso, muchisimas gracias

Comment: bueno gbianchi, acabo de leer ya el como responder, las siguientes preguntas las haré segun esas pautas, no quise reenviar la pregunta nomas y actué a las apuradas solo porque tengo que entregarlo mañana y me quede caliente con el error ese jajaja